# Error Message "DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension:...System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT"

Tags: devtools

The full error message is:

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

I am trying to skip the first two pages and get to the final booking screen to book a golf tee time. The https is below, but when I copy-paste it into the URL bar, it tries to load, but then kicks me back to the first booking screen instead of loading the final booking screen. The URL used to be different and all I had to do was change the date in the URL and it would take me directly to the final page of the date and time I wanted, but the site creator recently changed the URL to the one below and now it won't let me skip to the final page. It looks like it tries to load, fails, and then kicks me to the first page of the booking site. I have tried disabling all extensions but that did not solve. I tried to whitelist the URL, but that also didn't solve it. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

[Refer. Link here](https://letsgo.golf/los-verdes-golf-course/teeTimeCheckout/los-verdes-golf-course-california?allCartSelected=true&allRatesSelected=true&courseName=Los%20Verdes%20Golf%20Course&date=2023-08-24&holesGroupText=18&is_riding=true&major_rate_type=regular&max_hour=21&max_price=500&min_hour=5&min_price=0&minor_rate_type=Los%20Verdes%20Public%20Times&num_holes=18&playersGroupText=2%20-%0A%20%20%20%20%20%204&qty=2&rate_type=is_regular_rate&time_slot=6%3A30%3A00%20PM&transportText=Cart%20Included&transportTextRate=Cart%20Included)